# Why is my https:// request cancelled and changed to http://, causing a mixed request error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, https, mixed-content

I've got some simple lazy-loading javascript:

```
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://example.com/'+urlToJavascript;
script.onreadystatechange = callback;
script.onload = callback;   
head.appendChild(script);
```

SSL is running on my domain, https://example.com/. 
Despite `https` being in the script.src I get this mixed content error:

`The page at 'https://example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://example.com/js/lazyScript.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

I run `console.log(script)`, which shows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/js/lazyScript.js"></script>
```

Then I head over to Network tab of inspector and find that an initial request for `https://example.com/js/lazyScript.js` is made but subsequently CANCELLED, followed by a request for the insecure `http://example.com/js/lazyScript.js` which is then BLOCKED because of mixed content.

I've never come across this before and have no idea why this might be happening.

Any reason why this is happening?

Comment: Do you get any security errors when you visit https ://example.com/js/lazyScript.js directly? Does it stay on https?

Comment: Ha! You're right @Yashua. I didn't check that. Visiting the script directly causes a 404 error, but before the 404 there is a re-direct from https to http. I wasn't expecting that so it threw me.

Comment: @Yashua post an answer that I can accept if you want. Sorry this one was a bit of a no-brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be due to some rewrites at server level. I also faced same issue and it was nginx somehow converting a url back to http. Try to load the resource url directly in browser and see if there are redirects happening. If yes go back to the server and fix redirects.